# Cannot Change Method Name in PHPUnit

Tags: php, methods, phpunit, naming

I am running PHPUnit 4.2.2 inside a local Composer install. I'm also running PHP CodeSniffer 2.2.0.

I have written this unit test:

```
<?php

        include_once 'animals/Cat.php';

        class CatAgeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

         public function testTrueIsTrue(){

            $kittyAgeTest = new Cat("steak");
            $result = $kittyAgeTest->getAge() >=5 && $kittyAgeTest->getAge() <= 10;
            $this->assertTrue($result);

            }
        }

    ?>
```

It passes, until I change the method name. It's the only thing I've changed, and I've tried many different names. Here are a couple of examples:

```
testCatAgeBetweenFiveAndTen
catAgeTest
catAgeShouldBeBetweenFiveAndTen
```

... and so on.

Here's my phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

I have several other unit tests -- in different projects, with the same configuration -- on the same computer. I have tried changing their names, but it doesn't cause them to fail.

I've used these commands to run php unit:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit

vendor/bin/phpunit tests/CatAgeTest.php
```

Here is my composer.json file (just in case it helps):

```
{
    "require": {
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.2.2",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "animals": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Here's my Cat.php file:

```
<?php

    include_once("Animal.php");

    class Cat extends Animal{

        protected $name;
        protected $species;
        protected $speakCount;
        protected $age;

        public function __construct($name = "MewMew") {                              
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->age = rand(5, 10); // Random age
            $this->species = "Feline"; // For testing in the DB
            $this->namesHist = array(); // Names history
            array_push($this->namesHist, $name); 
        }

        public function getAge(){
            return $this->age;
        }

        public function getSpecies(){ // For testing in the DB
            return $this->species;
        }

        public function speak($word = "Meow.") { // Spoken word and word count               
                $this->speakCount += 1;

                $this->speakCount % 5 == 0 ? $this->age += 1 : $this->age;

                return $word;
            }

        public function getSpeakCount() {
            return $this->speakCount;
        }

        public function setName ($newName) {
            $this->name = $newName;
            array_push($this->namesHist, $newName);
        }

        public function getNames() {
            return $this->namesHist;
        }

        public function getAverageNameLength() {

            $nameLen=0;

            foreach($this->namesHist as $i) {
                $nameLen += strlen($i);
            }

            $avgNL = round($nameLen/(count($this->namesHist)), 2);
            return "Average Name Length: " . $avgNL;

        }
    }

    ?>
```

... and here's my Animal.php file:

```
<?php

    Class Animal {

        protected $name;
        protected $age;
        protected $favoriteFood;

        public function __construct($name, $age, $favoriteFood) {
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->age = $age;
            $this->favoriteFood = $favoriteFood;
        }

        public function getName() {
            return $this->name;
        }

        public function getAge() {
            return $this->age;
        }

        public function getFavoriteFood() {
            return $this->favoriteFood;
        }

        public function setName ($newName) {
            $this->name = $newName;
        }

        public function setAge ($newAge) {
            $this->age = $newAge;
        }

        public function setFavoriteFood($newFavoriteFood) {
            $this->favoriteFood = $newFavoriteFood;
        }
    }

?>
```

Edit2:

Here's the error I get:

```
PHPUnit 4.2.2 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /var/www/php/misc/ap/phpunit.xml

F

Time: 15 ms, Memory: 2.75Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) Warning
No tests found in class "CatAgeTest".

FAILURES!                            
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: Provide error message you are getting after changing  name.

Comment: I added the error to the post. Thanks...

Comment: `testCatAgeBetweenFiveAndTen()` should be a valid test name. The others would fail as expected because they aren't public methods named as `test*` https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html

Comment: That solved it! Thank you SO much!!!! Please answer it properly so I can give you the credit for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning PHPUnit issued indicates it found no test methods in your test class.

```
1) Warning
No tests found in class "CatAgeTest".
```

PHPUnit will accept methods named beginning with `test*()` and having `public` visibility as test methods.  It is also possible to declare a method outside that naming convention with the `@test` docblock attribute to designate it as a test method.

These method naming and description conventions [are documented here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html)

> The tests are public methods that are named test*.
>
> Alternatively, you can use the @test annotation in a method's docblock to mark it as a test method.

Given this requirement, your attempted method name `testCatAgeBetweenFiveAndTen()` should be a valid test method for PHPUnit.

Your other stated naming attempts do not meet PHPUnit's requirement and would not be found (`catAgeTest(), catAgeShouldBeBetweenFiveAndTen()`) unless you also annotate them with the `@test` attribute:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function catAgeTest(){
    $kittyAgeTest = new Cat("steak");
    $result = $kittyAgeTest->getAge() >=5 && $kittyAgeTest->getAge() <= 10;
    $this->assertTrue($result);
}
```